# How do you change email address on trainer account

Tags: pokemon-go

I am using the Pokimon Go trainer club and it won't let me go on the app as a message pops up saying 'please active your account in order to play' 
ButI have forgotten the email address I used originally when signing up.

Can I change the email address on my account?

I know my user ID and password.

I'm hoping I don't lose or have to restart as I collected Pokimon already.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging in to [the Pokemon Trainer Club site](https://sso.pokemon.com/sso/login) and accessing your account from there? It has the option to let you change your email in the profile settings.